# how to create node for ecommerce display page?

Tags: nodes

I am new to drupal [ecommerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).

I created one product type as service for that I have to create a service  display content type using node, how can I create this node ? and how to enable that node ?

Thanks,

Vinudha

Answer (score 0):

There is a module [Auto Product Display](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_auto_product_display)

This module will do automatically create product display for you.

> This module is created in order to solve that problem. This module can
>   simplify the Product Display creation process by providing option the
>   create it at the same time with Product creation.
>
> **Features**
>
> 1. Provide the Product Display creation form along with the Product
>      creation form. User can fill that form to create Product Display at
>      the same time with Product creation.
> 2. That form, which used to create Product Display, will be the same as
>      the form when user try to create Product Display manually. So, If
>      you have additional fields in your Product Display node type, those
>      fields will also appear in the form.
> 3. If the product is referenced by only one Product Display, the
>      Product Display content is displayed directly to the form, so it
>      will be automatically updated when you save the product.
> 4. If the product is referenced by more than one Product Display, the
>      referencing Product Displays will be displayed in list, so you can
>      also update the Product Display by clicking the link from that list
>      first.

If you want to create manually, this will guide you

"Product Display" is the default content type that Commerce Kickstart 1.x creates and it has a product reference field. Technically, any entity that has a product reference field could be considered a product display. Nodes are the obvious product display entity type, and they're privileged because they're the default and standard entity type to use for the front-end display of content. But you could use taxonomy vocabularies, or even users as product displays.

Taken reference from [here](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-displays)

Basically you need to add product reference field field for your node.